# How to convert list of dictionaries into a tree like nest dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have my data in this format -

```
data = {
    "label": "xyz.com",
    "children": [
        {
            "parent": "abc.com",
            "label": "user-3",
            "depth": 1
        },
        {

            "parent": "xyz.com",
            "label": "abc.com",
            "depth": 0
        },
        {

            "parent": "xyz.com",
            "label": "user-1",
            "depth": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to generate a result that looks like this (nested dictionary) -

```
result = {
    "label": "xyz.com",
    "children": [
         {

             "parent": "xyz.com",
             "label": "user-1",
             "depth": 0
         },
        {

            "parent": "xyz.com",
            "label": "abc.com",
            "depth": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "parent": "abc.com",
                    "label": "user-3",
                    "depth": 1
                }
            ]
         }

    ]
}
```

The initial dictionary is converted into a nested dictionary using **labels** - **parent** and **depth**.

Also, there could be any number of children. For example -

```
result = {
    "lable": "xyz.com",
    "children": [
         {
             "parent": "xyz.com",
             "label": "user-1",
             "depth": 0
         },
        {

            "parent": "xyz.com",
            "label": "abc.com",
            "depth": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "parent": "abc.com",
                    "label": "user-3",
                    "depth": 1,
                    "children": [
                        {...}, {...}
                    ]
                }
            ]
         }
    ]
}
```

Not sure if recursion is the way to go or is there some other solution out there.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much more efficient and single-pass, linear approach is to build a dict that maps labels to nodes, so that you can easily obtain the parent node by simply looking up the parent's label in the dict, and append the node to the parent node's `children` sub-list. Use `dict.setdefault` to initialize a dict entry for the parent node first if an iteration arrives at a child node earlier than its parent node, so that the parent node can later update itself with the pre-existing `children` entry:

```
result = {'label': data['label']}
nodes = {data['label']: result}
for node in data['children']:
    node.update(nodes.get(node['label'], {}))
    nodes[node['label']] = node
    nodes.setdefault(node['parent'], {}).setdefault('children', []).append(node)
```

`result` becomes:

```
{'label': 'xyz.com',
 'children': [{'parent': 'xyz.com',
               'label': 'abc.com',
               'depth': 0,
               'children': [{'parent': 'abc.com',
                             'label': 'user-3',
                             'depth': 1}]},
              {'parent': 'xyz.com', 'label': 'user-1', 'depth': 0}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
data = {'label': 'xyz.com', 'children': [{'parent': 'abc.com', 'label': 'user-3', 'depth': 1}, {'parent': 'xyz.com', 'label': 'abc.com', 'depth': 0}, {'parent': 'xyz.com', 'label': 'user-1', 'depth': 0}]}
def group(d):
  new_d = [i for i in d if all(c.get('label') != i.get('parent') for c in d)]
  c = [(lambda x:{a:b for a, b in x.items() if a != 'children' or b})({**i, 'children':[*i.get('children', []), *[j for j in d if j.get('parent') == i['label']]]}) for i in new_d]
  return [i if 'children' not in i else {**i, 'children':group(i['children'])} for i in c]
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(group([data]), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "label": "xyz.com",
    "children": [
        {
            "parent": "xyz.com",
            "label": "abc.com",
            "depth": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "parent": "abc.com",
                    "label": "user-3",
                    "depth": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "parent": "xyz.com",
            "label": "user-1",
            "depth": 0
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler implementation of a recursive approach would be to take advantage of the keys already in the dicts and mutate the dicts instead of creating new ones:

```
def convert(nodes, parent):
    children = [convert(nodes, node) for node in nodes if node['parent'] == parent['label']]
    if children:
        parent['children'] = children
    return parent
```

so that `convert(data.pop('children'), data)` returns:

```
{'label': 'xyz.com',
 'children': [{'parent': 'xyz.com',
               'label': 'abc.com',
               'depth': 0,
               'children': [{'parent': 'abc.com',
                             'label': 'user-3',
                             'depth': 1}]},
              {'parent': 'xyz.com', 'label': 'user-1', 'depth': 0}]}
```